# jQuery: Send Array

Tags: php, jquery

How do I send an array from PHP to jQuery?

I have many `<input type = "text" id = "search_term" />`. How can I send this data to jQuery?

```
<head>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#button1').click(function(){
        var search_val=$("#search_term").val(); 

        $.post("ajax.php",
          { search_term : search_val },
          function(data) {
            $("#search_results").html(data);
          }
        );
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type = "text" id = "search_term" />
  <input type = "text" id = "search_term" />
  <input type = "text" id = "search_term" />
  ...
  <input type = "button" id = "button1" value = "test" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use JSON.

**PHP SCRIPT**

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

**JQuery**

```
$.post("ajax.php", {search_term : search_val},
            function(data){
                var data=$.parseJSON(data); //Now "data" contains the php array
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use JSON. From your php, you do `json_encode($output)` where `$output` is your array, and in jQuery you use either [`getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method, or use `$.ajax` with the option `dataType: 'json'`.